# What is this part?

Tags: design, tool-identification, hardware-identification

I'm willing to give a $200 reward on this, if it's not against StackExchange policy. I know this is Woodworking but I'm hoping leads me in the right direction with folks who like creating/working with with their hands who might have the missing piece of knowledge I seek.

This is a telescopic extension arm that was repurposed for a painter's easel. The artist in question who built this easel lives in Australia, so it's possible it's some kind of vintage part specific to the region, but not necessarily.

I'm building my own easel, and while it diverges in a lot of ways, I want this exact telescopic arm.

It's critical I emphasize this... I want the exact part, and I don't want to discuss "why does it have to be exact when any old one will do?" Every time I ask on a forum or somewhere, 80% of the time is spent looking over suggestions that are nothing even remotely close, as well as having to explain why I don't want a similar part. I'd like to avoid all that noise, and focus on ideas of its exact origin.

I have spent hours upon hours scouring Google Images, TinEye, ChatGPT4-V, forums, etc. I KNOW it is out there somewhere, I just need to encounter the right person who knows.

I can ask the artist, but I don't want to bother him just yet unless its my absolute last resort.

---

The most unique aspect of it that I notice is that a cross-section of the arm is square/rectangle. Almost every telescopic arm I can find is either round or flat, so I'm hoping that helps narrow it down.

The main things i've been looking at are window stays, camper window telescopic arms, drafting table support arms, etc etc. It's possible it's still something I searched, but just didn't look at vintage product model X, etc.

The artist likes to repurpose things, so I'm assuming it's a vintage part. Another user in "Home Improvement" commented that it might be custom made though.

Here are a few images of it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you really don't want to bother the artist (imho, you should, as I'm sure he'd be tickled by the question), you can approach a machine shop and have them fab you up something. The hardest part will be getting exact dimensions.

Comment: Your question is really texty, but what is your actual question?

Comment: @Johannes_B The question is literally the title of the post...

Comment: @Tallboy, while that's literally true, by posting all that text you force potential responders (conscientious ones at least) to read through it all to make sure they're not answering counter to the hopes of the Q. This could be edited down to perhaps five paragraphs or so without losing any of the critical info, making it much easier to digest and, as I recently was forced to discover, *far far* easier to read on mobile devices.

Comment: *This is assuming they are not user-made* (bar the antique wing nut). Although it might seem next to impossible to the uninitiated to make something like this literally from scratch it's actually a trivially easy project for many a home machinist. The right person could knock out a matching pair in just a day if they had the right gauge plate or rolled steel in stock. An explanation for the old wing nut is they are prized by certain aficionados who would go out of their way to collect them, for use in projects like this, for both aesthetic & practical reasons (larger wings than modern ones).

Comment: wow... fascinating. Thank you.... thats super interesting about the wing nut. Does it have a kind of name? Id like to read more about it (that style, specifically). And you are correct, to myself, the uninitiated it seems near impossible to me

Comment: Sorry about offtopic, but not only has he (the artists) interesting easel-box, but also his paintings are amazing! (https://www.josephzbukvic.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that didn't take very long, I emailed the artist and he responded..... in three minutes!!

> What is this part?

They were **homemade from curtain rails**.

I know you specifically didn't want anything except the exact part but he suggests caravan spare parts shops for an easier alternative — window stays.

Comment: I’d give a thousand upvoted if I could!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, :-))))) I didn't even have time to add a Comment above that I thought your IMHO was so correct that I was going to try emailing the artist myself!

Comment: haha!!! wow, thanks..... thats so funny you did that... Well I suppose I should say the reason I didn't want to, it is because I'm not very hands on at all, and I quite literally have 100 questions. I've been trying to save off for asking questions unless I'm absolutely certain I can't figure it out, just to have a few questions in my back pocket. So thanks for doing that. now this really narrows down how to look

Comment: I suppose Ill just start by looking at vintage curtain rails, thank you!!

Comment: Welcome! Thought it couldn't hurt to ask. Not that I was expecting an answer in anything like this timeframe (hoped at best I might get a response within a week!) BTW if the aesthetic detail of these exact wing nuts is important to you then I sorely misinformed you above, they are apparently still being made :-) Something I read (published in the 1980s), from a very reliable source, led me to believe they were already becoming impossible to purchase all the way back then, but I just did a search for "cast wing nut" and new-stock items *are* out there from some vendors.

Comment: I was going to say they looked very familiar to me, I've seen similar things on an old camper I used to have.

Comment: Huh... I'd swear there was a comment on the OP suggesting that he ask the artist...

Comment: @FreeMan, I only saw the IMHO thing in parenthesis from AloysiusDefenestrate. If there were such a standalone Comment it could have been removed, in line with the current Code of Conduct (which is why I didn't post one exactly like that).